# C: unix socket -> broken pipe

Tags: c, sockets, unix

I'm trying to get a socket working in C code instead of calling the command line find.

the child 3'sort' function piped to the child2 function 'cut' work fine, and the program gets stuck in the parent process waitpid() when all 3 child functions are included when executed.

I've tried to isolate the only childs who participate on the socket and when I ran the executable on gdb I get the message "find: 'standard output': Broken pipe" and "find: write error"

Here's an example of the two child functions interacting with the socket:
Child 1:

```
void child1()
{
    int sock;
    struct sockaddr_un  remote;

    sock = socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0)
    memset(&remote, 0, sizeof(struct sockaddr_un));
    remote.sun_family = AF_UNIX;
    strncpy(remote.sun_path, "socket", sizeof(remote.sun_path) - 1);

    while((connect(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&remote,   (socklen_t)sizeof(remote))) == -1)
    {
        if(errno != ENOENT && errno != ECONNREFUSED)
            erro("child 2 failed to connect to socket");
    }
    dup2(sock, 1);
    close(sock);
    execlp("find", "find", ".", "-type" , "f", "-ls", NULL);
}
```

And Child2:

```
void child2(int *pipe_fd)
{
    int sock;
    struct sockaddr_un local, remote;
    socklen_t sock_size = (socklen_t)sizeof(remote);

    sock= socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    memset(&local, 0, sizeof(struct sockaddr_un));
    memset(&remote, 0, sizeof(struct sockaddr_un));

    local.sun_family = AF_UNIX;
    strncpy(local.sun_path, "socket", sizeof(local.sun_path) - 1);
    unlink("socket");
    bind(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&local, sizeof(struct sockaddr_un));

    listen(sock, 1);
    sock = accept(sock,(struct sockaddr *)&remote, &sock_size));
    dup2(sock, STDOUT_FILENO);
    close(sock);

    close(pipe_fd[0]);
    dup2(pipe_fd[1],1);
    close(pipe_fd[1]); 
    execlp("cut", "cut", "-d", " ", "-f", "3-", NULL);
}
```

There's no need to solve this problem in specific, I'm just trying to understand what I'm doing wrong in the creation process so I don't do it again in the future. 
I apreciate any help in advance.

Comment: Both children are writing to the same socket. Is that really what you want?

Comment: `child2` never execs anything.

Comment: Why is `child2` connecting stdout to the socket? Isn't it supposed to be the reader?

Comment: You get "Broken pipe" if you try to write to the socket after the reading process has closed the socket. Where is the reading process?

Comment: If `}` is the end of child 2, the receiver of the `find` output (inexplicably duped to STDOUT_FILENO there) will get implicitly closed there and that will break the socket for child1.

Comment: the child2 doesn't actually end where i put it I'm sorry my bad it's supposed to write to a pipe, I'm going to edit this give me 2 minutes

Comment: I want the child2 to read from the socket and transmit it through the pipe afterwards, where a child3 will recieve the final data and write it to a text file.

Comment: please post code that is complete, cleanly compiles, is short, and still exhibits the problem.  I.E. start with a `main()` function and post the necessary `#include` statements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I change `dup2(sock, STDOUT_FILENO);` into `dup2(sock, STDIN_FILENO);` in `child2` (the input there is the sock, and the output is the pipe that leads to `child3`), your example basically works:

(error checking needed)

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/un.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
void child1()
{
    int sock;
    struct sockaddr_un  remote;

    sock = socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    memset(&remote, 0, sizeof(struct sockaddr_un));
    remote.sun_family = AF_UNIX;
    strncpy(remote.sun_path, "socket", sizeof(remote.sun_path) - 1);

    while((connect(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&remote,   (socklen_t)sizeof(remote))) == -1)
    {
        perror("connect");
        if(errno != ENOENT && errno != ECONNREFUSED)
            perror("child 2 failed to connect to socket");
    }
    dup2(sock, 1);
    close(sock);
    execlp("find", "find", ".", "-type" , "f", "-ls", (char*)0);
}
void child2(int *pipe_fd)
{
    int sock;
    struct sockaddr_un local, remote;
    socklen_t sock_size = (socklen_t)sizeof(remote);

    sock= socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    memset(&local, 0, sizeof(struct sockaddr_un));
    memset(&remote, 0, sizeof(struct sockaddr_un));

    local.sun_family = AF_UNIX;
    strncpy(local.sun_path, "socket", sizeof(local.sun_path) - 1);
    unlink("socket");
    bind(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&local, sizeof(struct sockaddr_un));

    listen(sock, 1);
    puts("listened");
    sock = accept(sock,(struct sockaddr *)&remote, &sock_size);
    dup2(sock, STDIN_FILENO);
    close(sock);

    close(pipe_fd[0]);
    dup2(pipe_fd[1],1);
    close(pipe_fd[1]); 
    execlp("cut", "cut", "-d", " ", "-f", "3-", (char*)0);
}
void child3(int *pipe_fd)
{
    dup2(pipe_fd[0],0);
    close(pipe_fd[0]);
    execlp("sort", "sort", (char*)0);
}

int main()
{
    int pi[2];
    pid_t pid0, pid1, pid2;
    pid0 = fork();
    if (0==pid0){
        child1();
        _exit(1);
    }
    pipe(pi);
    pid1 = fork();
    if(0==pid1){
        child2(pi);
        _exit(1);
    }
    close(pi[1]);
    pid2 = fork();
    if(0==pid2){
        child3(pi);
        _exit(1);
    }
    close(pi[0]);

    wait(0);
    wait(0);
    wait(0);
}
```

This would be basically a triple pipe:

```
find | cut | sort
```

where the first `|` is not a regular pipe but rather a UNIX socket connection through `"socket"`.

Comment: Thank you! I really need to set my mind into checking these errors.